# A relationship between programming graphs and probability axioms.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I've been looking into both Computer Science algorithms as well as working through a book for applied probability for programming. And I think I thought there might be an interesting interpretation when we have probabilities larger than $1$. As strange as it sounds.

There is a well known algorithm that computes, given an adjacency matrix for a graph, in how many ways it is possible to get to node $B$ from node $A$. What we do is simply compute the adjacency matrix $M$ to the $n-th$ power. The entry $i,j$ will answer how many ways, going around the graph, it is possible to get exactly to the node.

On the other hand, people less concerned with algorithms for graph problems are better acquainted with the probability transition matrix, which for each row $i$, the $j-th$ entry contains the probability $P_{i,j}$, which is the probability of being in state $i$ and then moving to state $j$. In this case, each row of the matrix adds up to one: eventually the node will transition to some other state.

Let's look at an example of an adjacency matrix:

$$
A =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \end{array}
\right)
$$

So the graph looks like:

[image: Graph]

On the other hand, a probability transition matrix may look like:

$$
T =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
.3 & .3 & 0 & .4 & 0 \\
0 & .5 & .5 & 0 & 0 \\
.7 & 0 & .3 & 0 & 0 \\
.1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & .9 \\
.25 & .25 & .25 & 0 & .25 \end{array}
\right)
$$

Let's try calculating the $3$rd power.

$$
A^3 =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 5 & 5 & 4 & 2 & 2 \\
 3 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 0 \\
 4 & 3 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
 5 & 5 & 4 & 2 & 2 \\
 8 & 7 & 7 & 3 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$
T^3 =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 0.1755 & 0.1575 & 0.1485 & 0.036 & 0.1485 \\
 0.189 & 0.09 & 0.081 & 0.063 & 0. \\
 0.21 & 0.189 & 0.09 & 0.126 & 0.189 \\
 0.29325 & 0.20925 & 0.20025 & 0.0765 & 0.08325 \\
 0.265625 & 0.173125 & 0.143125 & 0.09375 & 0.083125 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

The way to interpret $A^3$ and $T^3$ is oddly similar. Which led me do the question: could we interpret the adjacency matrix as a "parallel worlds" matrix? That would be equivalent to saying that we take all the routes in every step. Which makes some sense.

I have yet to find other processes or algorithms that seems to exploit this "parallel world" probability version.

We could say that if $P(A) = 2$, then the event $A$ will happen in two different $\Omega$. This is over the board, but if someone can make some sense, or completely refute it, I'd appreciate the comments. Is this possible? Is it nonsense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Which led me do the question: could we interpret the adjacency matrix as a "parallel worlds" matrix?

Pretty much so.

A transition matrix *is* an adjacency matrix but one where the paths from any node are assigned probability measures rather that a Boolean.

An adjacency matrix merely reports which paths are open.   A transition matrix further measures how likely the paths are to be taken at any junction.